# Angular 2 show sidebar hidden by ngIf after login

Tags: angular

I have an Angular app with a main container component and a sidebar. A parent component contains both. The main container is also the main and only router output for the rest of components.

The sidebar template looks for a specific key in`sessionStorage`, if the key is not there, it removes itself from the DOM. I'm using`ngOnInit` to check`sessionStorage` and`*ngIf` to show/hide the component.

If the key is not in`sessionStorage`, sidebar hides itself and user is redirected to`/login`, which component is displayed on the main container component. When the user logs in sucessfully, the key is set in`sessionStorage`, and the user is redirected to`'/'` (which loads the initial screen for a logged in user on the main container), but the sidebar stays hidden/removed.

How can I make the sidebar appear again? Do I need to fire an event, and/or add the component again dynamically through the parent component?

Thank you.

Comment: Yes, the authentication service should emit an event on an observable, that the sidebar should subscribe to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your app.component.ts you can subscribe to router events to do this e.g.

```
import { OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor(private router: Router) { }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.router.events.subscribe(() => {
            this.showSidebar = // check if it exists
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: It worked!
When I asked, the ngIf was in the sidebar template itself (the sidebar component template contained the ngIf), so I moved the ngIf to the parent component and applied your solution. I was worried I needed to implement more complex elements.
Thank you.

Comment: @JamieR  Thanks for the answer.I have used this code in my AppComponent. In my application, this particular code to 'check if the user exists' has been called multiple times (3-4 times). Is there any way I could check it once? Let's say only if the new component is getting loaded. Sorry if i am being unclear.

Comment: @Sangram might be worth opening another question as it's not really related to the original question.
But i'm not sure how you would do that since you are subscribing to the routing events in the above example